# Exporting DLL API and Factory with impls from same DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

Okay, I'm starting to understand why its called Dll Hell.
This is the code I got

```
// API.h file
#ifdef EXPORTS
    #define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct API IClass {
   virtual void foo() = 0;
}

extern "C" API IClass* CreateClass(const char* type);

// Impl1.h
class Impl1: public IClass
{
   //...
}

// API.cpp file
#include "Impl1.h"
#include "Impl2.h"
#include "ImplX.h"

extern "C" API IClass* CreateClass(const char* type)
{
    if (type == "type1")
        return new Impl1();

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting linker warnings

```
warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0IClass@DG@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall IClass::IClass(void)) imported in function...
```

I understand this is occurring because I've imported those symbols in all my Impl's, but on the other hand, they are now local because I'm compiling them in the factory that is part of the API.

1) Should I ignore the warning or is there a different way to approach this ?
2) Should I leave the default __thiscall or change to __stdcall ?

**EDIT**
Not exporting `IClass` helped me remove the warnings.
Another issue arrises and I'm not sure the same method can fix this.
Let's assume `IClass` also has a method `virtual bar(IData* data) = 0`.
If I want clients to be able to create instances of `IData` I need to export it in the dll, returning to my original problem within the impl's. Unless I also create creation functions for them, but this seems a little much overhead for simple data structs.

So basically the question is, how do I expose `IData` to clients without having them exported in the DLL ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're aming at something like COM: there is no need to export the interface via

```
__declspec(dllexport|import).
```

Calling conventions are a rather old concept and are of any relevance on x64 (both Windows and UNIX only have one 64bit calling convention!) Your choice on 32bit would be between `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`. The number 1 rule should be: Stay consistent! Both these conventions are fine per se. (Unless you're are going to use `va_args` (which you shouldn't, as they are pure evilness)...)

`__stdcall` is used by COM and the WinAPI, whereas the standard libraries are mostly using `__cdecl`. In terms of performance it's completely irrelevant (there's a post somewhere here on stackoverflow on the speed difference of the calling conventions).

The warning may possibly result from the fact that you're exporting the class but not the constructor, therefor I'd recommend not to export the class...